# Is there a way to add .sqlproj to SSMS solution explorer?

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2017

I would like to add a .sqlproj (Visual Studio SQL Server Database Project) to SSMS Solution explorer.
When I go to File | Open Projects, this extension is not available

Answer (score 0):

No, SQL Server Management Studio is different product and works with it's own [projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/solution/projects-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-2017).

Projects in SSMS are collections of logically related scripts and files, that can be saved together, while projects in Visual Studio are much more than that. But you can execute SQL scripts from Visual Studio, if you want to use only one environment.